# Какими структурами лучше пользоваться для хранения данных?

Tags: база-данных, delphi

Собираюсь заняться курсовым проектом по Delphi. Тема - фильмотека (ну или каталогизатор фильмов, кому как нравится). Хочется помимо основной информации о фильме еще хранить ссылки на трейлеры и, например, картинку обложки. Какими структурами лучше пользоваться? Что сохранять в текстовые файлы, какие типизированные файлы и под что лучше использовать?

Comment: Это Делфи - там есть куча компонент для работы с базами. Скажу более - половину Ваших желаний можно сделать без написания кода. Откройте любую книгу по Делфи, где описаны базы данных и там это будет

Comment: Если речь идёт о текстовых и типизированных файлах, то это как бы намекает - базы данных ещё не проходили:)